# Route AJAX failure messages to console instead of popup

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

How can I prevent ajax failure popups and instead route the failure to the console log instead?  Is this something I can do with Drupals implementation of jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [Prevent JS alerts](https://drupal.org/project/prevent_js_alerts) module..

Project page says

> This module is an answer to the issue: [#1232416](https://drupal.org/node/1232416): Drupal alerts "An
>   AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally" during normal site operation,
>   confusing site visitors/editors, which describes a big problem for end
>   users: JavaScript alert();'s for end users on AJAX errors by Drupal
>   core. Perhaps it will one day become obsolete, when this bug is fixed.
>   End users are often frightened of these errors and don't know, if they
>   have "destroyed the internet" ;)
>
> This module completely suppresses ALL JavaScript alerts and instead
>   prints them to console via console.error! Important: It does NOT ONLY
>   suppress the core alerts, but also custom alerts.

Answer (score 1):

The prevent_js_alerts module is a heavy handed approach to handling ajax errors. If you want to intercept some errors, you can try something like this in your module or theme, which gives you a way of conditionally intercepting some messages, and letting Drupal do the default for everything else.

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.catchSomeDrupalAjaxAlerts = {

    attach: function(context, settings) {

      // Replace this simple core function with one that won't blurt empty messages.
      Drupal.displayAjaxError = function (message) {
        if (message && !Drupal.beforeUnloadCalled) {
          alert(message);
        }
      }

      // Intercept ajaxError to handle certain messages.
      Drupal.ajaxErrorDefault = Drupal.ajaxError;
      Drupal.ajaxError = function (xmlhttp, uri, customMessage) {
        var message = '';
        try {
          message = xmlhttp.error.message;
        }
        catch (e) {}

        // Handle various known cases.
        if (uri.indexOf('file/ajax') !== -1 && message == 'Unexpected end of JSON input') {
          // DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE
          $('body').append('<div class="error">SOMETHING HAPPENED PLEASE CONTACT 911</div>');
          return false;
        }
        else {
          // Passthru to the default Drupal.ajaxError if we don't want to intercept it.
          return Drupal.ajaxErrorDefault(xmlhttp, uri, customMessage);
        }
      }
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

This code is a variation of some project code, and may not work without some debugging. This solution is also similar to the module [ajax_error_behavior](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_error_behavior).